# Yii2 formatter relativeTime() is not working on shared host

Tags: yii2, shared-hosting, formatter, relative-date

It's working properly on local server, but when I upload it to the shared host, instead of displaying relative date it shows raw string.

code:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asRelativeTime($timestamp, 'now');
```

local host:

```
in 6 days
```

shared host:

```
in {delta, plural, =1{a day} other{# days}}
```

Locale is set and timestamp is being passed. Intl extension is enabled. Other formatter functions (i.e. asDate) are working properly.

Comment: Did you check if intl works? Try one of these [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.examples.basic.php). Log it or use VarDumper.

Comment: Yes, I have no problems with other formatter methods except of relativeTime()

Comment: Ok. I don't know the problem. However, [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7301) or this [might](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7430) help. If you find out anything please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it was because of outdated ICU library of PHP intl extension.
Mine was 4.2.1, while [yii2 requires at least ICU version 49 to be able to use all the features](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-i18n.md#setting-up-your-php-environment-), which probably include asRelativeTime().

Cannot say for sure because I'm unable to update it on my hosting plan.

Answer (score 0):

`in 6 days` is a localized string (English).

`in {delta, plural, =1{a day} other{# days}}` is the unlocalized template.

With each request Yii tries to localize the template. If Yii cannot localize the template for some reason it will output the template.

So it could be, that the localization files are missing: Check if `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages` contains the folders and files for your language. And check if the current localization is set to a valid value.

Read also about [internationalization with Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html).

Comment: Localization files are there. They are the same on both servers. Locale value is valid ("en" - the same as on localhost, and it works there).

Comment: @mt.andi Ok. And are they accessible (file permissions)? Do you use localization at all?

Comment: The files are readable, but English strings doesn't need those. Yes, I'm using localization - asCurrency() switches the numbers to Arabic ones properly.